# exec a perl command in Tcl with dollar sign

Tags: perl, tcl

I call a grep/perl command to extract a substring from a file in a tcl script. However I can't find a way to escape $ in perl script.

Here is my command:

```tcl
set varA [exec grep ^library $file | perl -pe 's/.*\(\s*"*(.*?)"*\s*\).*/$1/']
```

tcl will report error `no variable '1'`. I escaped `$` with `{$}` per some guidance, however the perl command just doesn't work after the `{}` escape. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the *entire* argument in curly braces to prevent evaluation:

```
set varA [exec grep ^library $file | perl -pe {s/.*\(\s*"*(.*?)"*\s*\).*/$1/}]
```

Or skip the `exec` and just do it all in tcl:

```
proc fetch_file {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set result ""
    while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
        if {[string equal -length 7 library $line]} {
            lappend result [regsub {.*\(\s*"*(.*?)"*\s*\).*} $line {\1}]
        }
    }
    close $f
    return [join $result \n]
}

set varA [fetch_file $file]
```

Comment: **Explanation:** braces in Tcl are *just like* single quotes in shell (except they nest nicely and have to start a word).

Comment: Brilliant, it works like a charm. Thanks Shawn and thank Donal for kind explanation.